Can a child take as props a function defined in the parent without taking props of the data in the function defined in the parent?
If a child component has props of a function passed from its parent, let's say function foo, but this function makes a call to another function, let's say function bar, and bar is only defined in the parent component, would we have to pass bar as props to the child as well?
function ParentComponent() {

//both bar and foo are defined in parent

return (
<>
<ChildComponent foo={foo} />
</>
);
}

function ChildComponent({ foo }) {
...
}

function foo() {
  
  bar() //defined in parent, not passed to child
}

I tried to pass a function as a prop to a child from a parent, but I am not sure what the result is because the function relies on variables defined in the parent

It should be fine. What happens when you try?

You don't have to pass the function called in the ParentComponent to the ChildComponent.
Here is an example...
export default function ParentComp() {
  const doSomethingElse = () => {
    console.log('Something else')
  }

  const handleSomething = (optional) => {
    console.log('Something')
    doSomethingElse()
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComp handleSomething={handleSomething} />
    </div>
  )
}

function ChildComp({ handleSomething }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleSomething}>Click me</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleSomething('Hello world')}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  )
}

